# String to Date, Accessing date only from Now function

Tags: excel, vba

I have the date and time in the following format:

```
7/12/2012 3:41
```

I want to keep only the date from this. I have tried to write a function to do this, but excel will only recognise this as a string so I am having difficulty editing the entry. If some one could help me with a function or direction to spilt off only the date portion of this it would be greatly appreciated.

My intended application is something along the lines of

```
  Public Function Change(X As Variant)
   '
   If X > Application.WorksheetFunction.Now() Then
   Change = 1
   End If
   '
  End Function
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert a DateTime to a Date in Excel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834080/how-can-i-convert-a-datetime-to-a-date-in-excel)

Comment: @chrisneilsen: That [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834080/how-can-i-convert-a-datetime-to-a-date-in-excel) was about Excel formulas and therefore was closed as off-topic (superuser) and is on the way to deletion. This question is about VBA, so not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends whether you are looking for a Date or a String as the output. Here's how to do both.

```
Dim strDateTime As String
Dim strDate As String
Dim s() As String
Dim pureDate As Date

strDateTime = "7/12/2012 3:41"
strDate = Split(strDateTime, " ")(0) ' "7/12/2012"
pureDate = CDate(strDate) ' 7 Dec 2012 (in my locale)
                          ' ... results may be ambiguous depending on your locale

'Another way to get a Date, not blindly using CDate:
s = Split(strDate, "/")
' if date in day/month/year format:
pureDate = DateSerial(CInt(s(2)), CInt(s(1)), CInt(s(0))) ' 7 Dec 2012
' or, if date in month/day/year format:
pureDate = DateSerial(CInt(s(2)), CInt(s(0)), CInt(s(1))) ' 12 July 2012
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Format` function like this:

```
Public Function Change(DateExp) As Date
'Format function lets you transform most data in your desired format.
'CDate handles any Date Expression conversion to Date data type.
'CStr handles any expression conversion to String data type
If IsMissing(ReturnType) Then
    'Return as Date, default when ReturnType is not supplied
    Change = Format(CDate(DateExp), "m/d/yyyy")
Else
    If ReturnType = True Then
        'Return as Date
        Change = Format(CDate(DateExp), "m/d/yyyy")
    ElseIf ReturnType = False Then
        Change = Format(CDate(DateExp), "m/d/yyyy")
        'Return as String
        Change = CStr(Change)
    Else
        'Error out any values other than TRUE or FALSE
        Change = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    End If
End If
End Function
```

But if you are really interested with returning just the date, use `Today() Function` instead of `Now()` (for WS).
Equivalent functionality in VBA is `Date` Function which return your systems current date.
Same